# How to get a value from a web table using Python Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I can access to the page. I can go to the location of the table using Selenium xpath.

```
driver.find_elements('xpath', "/html/body/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]")
```

[image]

The question is how I can get the value inside the cell?

Comment: Post the URL and the code you've tried to debug.

Comment: I cannot post the URL. It is a company internal website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the result of your expression to a variable which will be an array of element objects. Since you are directly referencing a `td` element, the array will only have one element, which should be the value you are looking for. To get this value, use `element[0].text`.

```
element = driver.find_elements('xpath', "/html/body/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]")
print(element[0].text)
```

Here is a simple example of it working with a generic HTML table from w3schools:

```
...
driver.get("https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp")
element = driver.find_elements('xpath', "/html/body/div[7]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]")
print(element[0].text)
```

> Output:
> Centro comercial Moctezuma